# Failed to read file modules.xml in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm getting this error:

[image]

And I'm not sure what to do. There is no `modules.xml` file in the specified folder, so how can I get it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Close Android Studio, if it's opened
2. Go to the project workspace *(Eg: C:\wheverever\it\is\TheProjectName)*
3. Delete **.idea** folder
4. Open Android Studio and re import that project into it.

Comment: I'm trying it, I hate how Android Studio makes me update the SDK >.<

Comment: Did it fix your issue?

Comment: Yes. Whats up with your username?

Comment: the usual. The best username I could come up with without it being already taken.